# [[anon:dalvik-DEX data]] o.k.PlaybackStateCompat$1 -- Crash in Playstore (React Native)

Tags: android, react-native

is anyone familiar with this kind of error? What we only added in the current version is the useFocusEffect where it has React.useCallback inside and this crash is occurring but cannot replicate it. I am not sure how it is related. Thanks for your help.

```
useFocusEffect(
 React.useCallback(() => {
     AppState.addEventListener("change", onAppStateChange);
     return () => {
         AppState.removeEventListener("change", onAppStateChange);
     }
 }, [])
```

I have tried researching about PlaybackMediaStateCompat and it is related to media. What we only have is animations to play and we don't have any changes on it. In addition, this crash is not recorded in app center and can only be seen in play console